# Share cookies with subdomain without php.ini

Tags: php, cookies

Is there any way to share a $_COOKIE variable between **sub.my-domain.com** and **my-domain.com** without using php.ini?

I've tried by adding this to the top of the pages (on both the main and the sub domain):

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".my-domain.com");
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: session.cookie_domain is for the session cookie, not cookies in general.  See @GeorgeBrighton's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), there is a parameter for the domain. This controls which domains will be able to access that cookie. In this example, `mycookie` can be accessed from `domain.com` and `*.domain.com`:

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'value', time() + 3600, '/', '.domain.com', 1);
```